# IE9 filter dropshadow bug?

Tags: css, input, internet-explorer-9

In IE9 the input isn't visible. Is it IE9 bug? It's caused by filter dropshadow.

```
input {
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: #e75012;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;

  text-shadow: 2px 1px 1px #000;
  filter: dropshadow(color=#000, offx=2, offy=1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That gives me an ugly mess, using:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(color=#000, offx=2, offy=1);
```

works, however its depreciated in IE9, instead you can use the superior;

```
box-shadow: #000 2px 2px;
```

Comment: box shadow only puts an outline around the box, it doesn't do a proper drop shadow of anything with an irregular shape (i.e. transparent pngs, transparent borders)

Answer (score 0):

As IE9 does not support CSS3 text-shadow, Check this link Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/dmM2S/